# How can I prevent sending twice http request in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0

I have a rest service, which is created in a Spring boot application.
I use Angular 6 and call this REST service.
When I send the http request to the Rest Service, that rest service is called twice.
How can I solve this issue?
Below is my service client code.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Payment} from './Payment';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Token} from './Token';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Home';
  token: Token;
  payments: Payment[];
  jwt = '';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getToken();
    console.log('dsdsd=>' + this.jwt);

  }

  getToken() {

    this.http.post<Token>('http://localhost:8084/login', JSON.stringify({ username: 'mehman', password: 'mehman' })
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.token = res.token;
        this.getPayments(res.token);
      });
  }

  getPayments(token: Token) {
    console.log(token);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', '' + token);
      this.http.get<Payment[]>('http://localhost:8084/payment/all', { headers: headers}
      )
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.payments = res;
          console.log(res);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see you make 2 REST-calls in a row. First `getToken()` and then `getPayments()`. Which service is called twice?